# ext.kotlin_version = <'latest version'> error en Flutter

Tags: flutter

Trato de colocar la publicidad en mi app flutter, esto esta siendo casi mas complicado para mi que crear la propia app (soy un dev novato que arranca con flutter).

Recibo un error cuando trato de lanzar mi aplicación que dice lo siguiente:
[!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.
Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html#plugin-and-versions, then update C:\Users\User\Desktop\Dev\adtest\android\build.gradle:
ext.kotlin_version = ''
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

El problema parece sencillo, debo hacer update del campo que sugiere la consola.
Mi sorpresa es que el campo ext.kotlin_version = " ", no existe en mi archivo build.grade.
Tampoco existe el apatartado de buildscript {  } que debe contenerlo.
Tengo instalado android Studio, Flutter updateado, trabajo con visual studio code, todo esta correcto aparentemente, salvo por esto.

Comment: Normalmente, la doc del plugin/s que estés usando, debería decirte qué dependencias necesitas actualizar. Intenta echarle un ojo y a ver si encuentras algo en la doc.

Comment: Entraste a la carpeta android/app/build.gradle ?

Comment: Si, como comento, el problema es justo ese, la linea que menciona no aparece en mi archivo build.gradle

Comment: Hay verificar cual es la versión recomendada, dejo el enlace de la versión gradle. - https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugins_block

Answer (score 0):

Debes de actualizar el archivo que esta en la ruta de `android/build.gradle`, no confundir con el de `android/app/build.gradle`.

Empieza desde la línea 1 y se debe ver algo así:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
```

Answer (score 0):

Este es el [enlace que necesitas](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html#plugin-and-versions)

Tienes un proyecto con una versión previa. En el archivo android\build.gradle actualiza ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'

[image: Mira esta imágen]